# How to further filter a result of ResultSet?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a list of all hrefs in a html document. I'm using Beautiful Soap to parse my html file.

```
print soup.body.find_all('a', attrs={'data-tag':'Homepage Library'})[0]
```

The result I get is:

```
<a class="m0 vl" data-tag="Homepage Library" href="/video?lang=pl&amp;format=lite&amp;v=AZpftzD9jVs" title="abc">
        text
    </a>
```

I'm interested in href="" part only. So I would like the ResultSet to return the value of href only.

I'm not sure how to extend this query, so it returns the href part.

Comment: U can refer this blog post and get a good understanding on this. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this worked for me:

```
soup.body.find_all('a', attrs={'data-tag':'Homepage Library'}).attrs["href"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [attrs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
links = soup.body.find_all('a', attrs={'data-tag':'Homepage Library'})
print [link.attrs['href'] for link in links]
```

or, get attributes directly from the element by treating it like a dictionary:

```
links = soup.body.find_all('a', attrs={'data-tag':'Homepage Library'})
print [link['href'] for link in links]
```

DEMO:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = """<body>
<a href="link1">text1</a>
<a href="link2">text2</a>
<a href="link3">text3</a>
<a href="link4">text4</a>
</body>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
links = soup.body.find_all('a')
print [link.attrs['href'] for link in links]
```

prints

```
['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'data-tag':'Homepage Library'}):
    print(link.get('href'))
```